# GOOGLE CUSTOM SEARCH API - (searches related to function)

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I need your help. I am looking to create a custom search engine.

I am currently looking at using the Google Custom search API. I tried looking into this but I couldn't find anything concrete.

Is there any way to setup related search words on a Google Custom search website? Is there any API that can generate **"searches related to"**?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and it's the desert out there!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a service by SimilarSites which outputs data very similar to the [Google Related API](http://dev.similarsites.com/similar-websites-api/), but they use their own proprietary algos.

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not atempt to answer it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure what you mean by "searches related to". Nevertheless for every single request in CSE API you can specify the following parameters:

1. linkSite - "Specifies that all search results should contain a link to a particular URL".
2. relatedSite - "Specifies that all search results should be pages that are related to the specified URL".
3. orTerms - "Provides additional search terms to check for in a document, where each document in the search results must contain at least one of the additional search terms".
4. hq - "Appends the extra query terms to the query".

More infos can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list).

May be it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several interesting APIs that can help you here.

- [Keywords Competitors API](https://developer.similarweb.com/organic_paid_search_comptetitors_pro_api) - This is an API that let you query a domain and get all the other domains that are competing on the same paid or organic search keywords.
- [Search Keywords API](https://developer.similarweb.com/keywords_api) - Another API that will provide all the leading keywords (paid and organic) for a given domain. This can even be broken down to specific countries.
- [SimilarWeb API](https://developer.similarweb.com/similar_websites_api) - Get more websites that are similar to a given domain, based on many different factors including keywords and tags.