# Is there a way of displaying 'Related searches' when using Google Custom Search API

Tags: web, google-custom-search

I am using the Google Custom Search API to display google search results on my website, however, I would like to display 'Related Searches' like the ones shown at the bottom of a normal google search.

Is this possible? And if so, how do you do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547584/google-custom-search-api-searches-related-to-function

Answer (score 1):

I know relatedQueries.enabled can be used in "get" format see the example for returned results as shown below, all from this link 
https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-content-module-related-queries

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=US&q=shoes&relatedQueries.enabled=true&key=key

{
 "kind": "shopping#products",
 ...
 "relatedQueries": [
  "jordan shoes",
  "nike shoes",
  "dc shoes",
  "puma shoes"
 ]
 ...
 "items": [
  ...
 ]
}
```

Comment: This is only for shopping?