# find "Related links" using Google custom search

Tags: google-search-api, google-custom-search

This has been asked [once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071156/is-there-a-way-of-displaying-related-searches-when-using-google-custom-search) about a year ago but no one could provide any answers.

If you go to Google and search for any key, for example "Soccer", at the very end of the search results there is a list:

```
Searches related to soccer
soccer live
soccer results
soccer games
soccer direct
soccer sports
soccer manager
soccer am
soccer heads
```

Is it possible to get this list by using the Google custom search XML API?

I am querying

```
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=myKey&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q=soccer
```

And the XML contains no such section.

There is in the documentation ([which is here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results)) a way to query URLs that are related to a particular URL but there is not way to query search keys that are related to a particular search key.

So how does google do it and is this functionality not exposed via the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Custom Search is about searching webpages, not suggesting similar or related terms. It offers autocompletion though, if this is enough for your needs.

There are other APIs that do suggesting, e.g. http://www.veryrelated.com/related-api-v1-docs.php.

Comment: Cool, that explains why I struggled to find a way of doing this